# Gridview items with different heights - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I'm having a problems showing items inside a gridview of 2 columns.

The problem, I think, it's related with the recycle process of the views.

The items in my gridview are items with a Text, so the height it's different in every item (depending on the text).

When I make a scroll down or up, sometimes items' height are not well calculated, and some rows are partially overlaping other rows...

What could I do to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution: http://obduro.nl/blog/the-solution-of-android-gridview-overlap/

The solution has explained on that link is to calculate each row height based on the height of all its elements (using maximum height).

After testing this, it works beautifully, except for one catch: Once a row size has been increased it will not decrease.

Actual code can be found here: https://github.com/JJdeGroot/AutoGridView

Comment: AutoGridView invokes the setMinimumHeight(int minHeight) method on nested views to set row height. So to decrease a row height after it has been increased, you can call the setMinimumHeight(int minHeight) method on your views and pass a small value to it. After that AutoGridView will adjust row height as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:id="@+id/grid_icon_layout"     
android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
android:gravity="center_horizontal"     
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/icon_text"         
    android:layout_width="90dp"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"         
    android:maxLines="2"         
    android:singleLine="false"         
    android:text="Samples Samples"         
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"         
    android:textSize="15dp"         
    android:typeface="serif" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain how that solves the issue mentioned in OP? All I see is that if you have an item with text that fits on one line and another that needs 2 lines, the next items will overlap. Instead the maxLines attributes is creating extra limitations that are very likely unwanted. I actually tried and it doesn't help at all.

Comment: you always has max lines then show elipse of cut the content.

Comment: understand this in that way